Borel Measurable function
Let $h: \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ be given by $h(z_1, z_2)=\frac{z_1z_2}{|z_1z_2|}$ when $z_1z_2 \ne 0$ and otherwise $h(z_1, z_2)=0$. My question is if this function $h$ is Borel-measurable.
I know this is equivalent to showing that the real and imaginary part of $h$ are Borel measurable real-valued functions. Also, $h$ is not continuous. But still could it be Borel measurable.

Let $h_n(z_1,z_2)=h(z_1,z_2)$ if $|z_1z_2|>\frac  1 n$ and $h_n(z_1,z_2)=nz_1z_2$ if $|z_1z_2|\le\frac  1 n$. Then $h_n$ is continuous for each $n$ and $h_n \to h$ pointwise.

The continuity part is clear. Why does it converge to h point wise as $n \to \infty$?

If $z_1z_2=0$ then $h_n(z_1,z_2)=h(z_1,z_2)=0$ for all $n$. Otherwise, $|z_1z_2|>\frac  1n$ for $n$ sufficiently large, so $h_n(z_1,z_2)=h(z_1,z_2)$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.  @Curious
